# Parameterized Constructor Object creation using name

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

```
class Point
{
private:
int x, y;
public:
Point()
{
}
// Parameterized Constructor
Point(int x1)
{
 x=x1;
}
Point(int x1, int y1)
{
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
}
int getX()
{
    return x;
}
int getY()
{
    return y;
}
};
int main()
{
   Point p(10);
   p = Point(50,100);
}
```

does Point(50,100) returns an object??Can Anyone explain the details about the execution in main function. for assigning p with Point(50,100) it should give an object.

Comment: It does returns an instance of `Point`, which in turn is assigned to the `p` using [implicitly-defined copy-assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) (memberwise copies all the data members, `x` and `y` in this case).

Comment: Why do you call it "parameterized constructor"? It is a regular constructor.

Comment: @IgorR i suspect some tutorial, for example this is a particularly poor one that uses the term and spreads more misinformation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Comment: fwiw, the distinction between a default constructor and a "parametrized constructor" as it is made eg in the link above is wrong and misleading. Default constructors can take parameters too, what distinguishes them is that they can be called without parameters. "parametrized constructor" is not a common term and neither is it very useful

Answer (score 1):

Here `Point(50,100)` creates an object then calls the assignment operator of the `class Point` which is generated as default by the compiler and basically copies memory of righthand operand into left hand operand. After copying, it also calls the destructor for the `Point(50,100)`.

You can check this by adding a destructor to your function.

```
~Point()
{
    std::cout<<"destructor"<<x<<std::endl;
}
```